# Permission to endpoint

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

I create my custom decorator to authenticate on every controller in my nest application like below:

```
export function AuthRequired(exposeOptions?: ExposeOptions): (arg0: Controller, arg1: string, arg3: TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>) => void {
  const exposeFn = Expose(exposeOptions);
  const apiBearerAuthFn = ApiBearerAuth();
  const guardFn = UseGuards(AuthGuard())


  return function (target: Controller, key: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<unknown>): void {
    apiBearerAuthFn(target, key, descriptor);
    guardFn(target, key, descriptor);
    exposeFn(target, key);
  }
}
```

but it not work and i have permission to all of my endpoint :/
in swagger it looks like that:[image]

this padlock must be close

can someone tell me what have i wrong?

below is my full code:

AuthService

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
      private jwtService: JwtService,
      private userService: UserService,
      private conn: Connection
    ) {}

  private async validate(userData: UserCredentials): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = this.userService.getUserByUsername(userData.username);
    if(user) {
      const isUserCorrect = await this.checkUserPassword(userData);
      if(isUserCorrect) return true;
    } else {
      throw new BadRequestException('User does not exist!');
    }
  }

  public async login(userData: UserCredentials): Promise< any | { status: number }>{
    const isLogged = await this.validate(userData);

    if(isLogged) {
      const user = await this.userService.getUserByUsername(userData.username);
      let payload = `${user.username}${user.id}${user.userType}`;
      const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload);

      return {
        userId: user.id,
        accessToken: accessToken
      }
    }
  }

  public async register(user: UserModel): Promise<any>{
      return this.userService.addUser(user)
  }

  async checkUserPassword(credentials: UserCredentials): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = await this.conn.getRepository(User).findOneOrFail({ username: credentials.username, password: createHmac('sha256', credentials.password).digest('hex') }).catch(() => {
        throw new NotFoundException('Bad password or user does not exist!');
      }
    );

    if(user) return true;
  }
}
```

AuthModule

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
        PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' })
    ],
    providers: [UserService],
    exports: [PassportModule]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

AppModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ///
    }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secretKey'
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, UserController, AuthController],
  providers: [AppService, UserService, AuthService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

AppController

```
    @Get()
    @AuthRequired()
    async getCurrentUser() {
        console.log();
    }
```

I have no idea what is wrong :/

swagger:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('title')
    .setDescription('desc')
    .setVersion('0.1')
    .addServer('/api', 'Main server - current/local')
    .build();
  
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api-doc', app, document);

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

  
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: Can you show us how you initialize swagger using `DocumentBuilder`?

Comment: @eol: i paste code at the bottom of main post, can yo look at this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/security), you're missing the security definition on your `DocumentBuilder`. Try adding the following:

```
const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('title')
    .setDescription('desc')
    .setVersion('0.1')
    .addServer('/api', 'Main server - current/local')
    .addBearerAuth() // <-- note this
    .build();
```

Comment: @OP: any feedback?